# Neo4j Subgraph Projection using a string inside string query

Tags: neo4j, projection

Working on a project, I was trying to reduce the number of variables to make something easier to visualize for creating embeddings and checking if they work.
I realized there was a projection and a subprojection. I can definitely create a new neo4j graph, but that seems like a slow solution.
so just following the tutorial, they have

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
  'apps_undir',
  ['App', 'Genre']
  {Genre_Category: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}}
)
```

then something like

```
CALL gds.beta.graph.project.subgraph(
  'subapps',
  'apps_undir',
  "n:App OR (n:Genre AND n.name = 'Action' OR n.name = 'RPG')",
  '*'
)
```

I realize this isn't python, but it's the idea I'm trying to express. With the string query as `'n:App OR (n:Genre AND n.name = Action OR n.name = RPG)'` I get the error:
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.beta.graph.project.subgraph`: Caused by: org.neo4j.gds.beta.filter.expression.SemanticErrors: Semantic errors while parsing expression:

```
Invalid variable `Action`. Only `n` is allowed for nodes
Invalid variable `RPG`. Only `n` is allowed for nodes
Unknown property `name`.
Unknown property `name`.
```

the error produced is
"Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Invalid input 'subgraph': expected"
As subgraph is only in beta functionality isn't great, but all node names apparently need to be n,
for the actual subgraph, and performing an embedding on that

if it helps, this was taken from a steam database scrape from 2016 and a couple csv values are below:

```
appid;Genre
8890;RPG
8890;Strategy
10530;Action
10530;RPG
15540;Indie
15560;Action
15620;Strategy
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your workflow. When you project a graph in GDS with the following command, it doesn't include any node properties by default.

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
  'apps_undir',
  ['App', 'Genre']
  {Genre_Category: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}}
)
```

There are ways to include node properties in the graph projections, however string format is not supported. Therefore, you cannot project the `name` property which appears to be a string. To achieve what you want to do you should probably use Cypher projection.

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher('subapps',
  'MATCH (n) WHERE n:App OR (n:Genre AND n.name IN ["Action", "RPG"]) RETURN id(n) AS id',
  'MATCH (s)-[:Genre_Category]-(t) RETURN id(s) AS source, id(t) AS target',
  {validateRelationship:false})
```

A couple of pointers for Cypher projection. To define the relationships I have used `(s)-[:Genre_Category]-(t)` pattern. Notice the lack of relationship direction. By avoiding the relationship direction definition, the relationships will be projected as "undirected". You need to include the `validateRelationship` parameter since you perform node filtering in the node projection, but not in the relationship projection.

Comment: validateRelationship is validateRelationships in neo4j (thank you for the answer), but there's a larger issue:

this seems like it might work, but trying the query a second time after using the projection query it gives me a NotInTransactionException: The transaction has been closed. I realize that's a different question, but currently, it doesn't work well. I'm using neo4j 5.2 if it matters, but I do have the database in a 4.4.14 format as well.

Comment: Edit: transactions may be related to jobId but I still haven't figured out how to stop, cancel, or reset other than waiting the 10 minutes

Comment: Do you perhaps run out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to create a named graph based on CQL that contained a string.

This did not work!

```
call gds.graph.project.cypher(
'calendar',
'match (n) where (n.Attendees_Names contains "jdoe@company.com") return 
id(n) as id',
'match (m)-[r:ATTENDS_MEETING]-(n) where (n.Meeting_Start_date.month = 1) 
AND (n.Meeting_Start_date.year =2023) return id(n) as source, type(r) as 
type,id(m) as target'
)
```

This worked!

```
match(source:Person)-[r:ATTENDS_MEETING]->(target:Calendar) 
where (target.Attendees_Names contains 'jdoe@company.com') 
AND (target.Meeting_Start_date.month = 1) 
AND (target.Meeting_Start_date.year =2023)

WITH gds.alpha.graph.project('attendees', source, target) AS g
RETURN
  g.graphName AS graph, g.nodeCount AS nodes, g.relationshipCount AS rels
```